# Flutter app not running screens with third-party dependencies (no error message)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, pub.dev

My laptop is stuck on a strange problem...No Flutter project is running...Need your help...

### Problem:

It appears that any flutter project that uses any dependency (except google_fonts) is not running. The screens without any dependencies work well, but when I try to switch from one screen to another where there is a dependency, it does not work. The screens get stuck or become blank white. There is even nothing available in the console...

### Flutter Doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.16.5 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 78666c8dc5 (10 weeks ago), 2023-12-19 16:14:14 -0800
    • Engine revision 3f3e560236
    • Dart version 3.2.3
    • DevTools version 2.28.4

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Kamal\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.9)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
    • Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 version 16.11.32106.194
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.86.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Kamal\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.80.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 122.0.6261.69
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 122.0.2365.52

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

### Flutter pub get:

```
PS D:\projects\live_tv> flutter run -d chrome
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
  matcher 0.12.16 (0.12.16+1 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
  meta 1.10.0 (1.12.0 available)
  path 1.8.3 (1.9.0 available)
  test_api 0.6.1 (0.7.0 available)
  video_player_web 2.1.3 (2.2.0 available)
  wakelock_plus 1.1.4 (1.1.6 available)
  web 0.3.0 (0.5.0 available)
Got dependencies!
11 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
```

*The issue Occur after I install latest android studio (hedgehog) and latest flutter version (3.19.1). After that I downgrade to 3.16.9 then again 3.16.5*

**Note** :

- flutter pub get in working well but if I am using dependencies in any screen then it's not working..
- Another problem is when I hit hot restart or hot reload didn't work even after 1 hour it shows hot reloading or hot restarting the app

**Tried:**

- Running on android emulator, real android device, web (chrom, edge) (still nothing is there in console)
- ```
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) { debugPrint(details.exception.toString()); };
  ```
- Clear pub caches and C drive caches
- flutter clean

Even existing running projects are not working...

Comment: Did you tried  invalidate caches and restart in Android Studio?

Comment: @JaiminRaval Yes I have tried clearing invalid caches also I have tried running on vs code but nothing changes..

Comment: Have you tried runing `flutter pub cache repair` ?

Comment: @MohanKumar Yes I have tried running `flutter pub cache repair` before also just right now but didn't work..

Comment: @AnikChakraborty which dependecy you are using while switching to another screen as you mentioned in question ?

Comment: @HardikMehta I am trying to navigate to another screen using basic `Navigator.push()` . Where ever I am using any dependency (except Google font) like Getx, flutter_dotenv, http and other popular dependency it's creating issue ... The screen gets stuck and only shows blank white screen... even hot reload and hot restart gets stucked.

Comment: did you set that dependency correctly ?  or share the logs by running app with  flutter run -v

Comment: @HardikMehta Yes. Because previous exiting projects was working well. 
Here is the link of `flutter run -v` log https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DYBmiFaDR6wWIGYE39HTy-2P6E-6LBWRuqxhleT7joM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AnikChakraborty is there any logs in console of browser  when you run your app ?

Comment: @HardikMehta No. The console is clean

Comment: did you added this statement  by your self ?  ExpressionEvaluator: Evaluated

Comment: @HardikMehta No.